# How to change embedded tomcat's version in existing spring boot app?

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I'm currently running `spring-boot version 1.4.0.RELEASE` application with embedded tomcat. Included Tomcat's version is `8.5.4`

There's a need to update the tomcat version to `9.x`. When I looked at mvnrepository [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.4.0.RELEASE), I found that there's an update available to tomcat version `9.0.5` (shown in pic below)

[image]

How should I use this version in my project if there's no way to directly mention this version in my `pom.xml`?

I do not want to go the traditional deployment route (WAR artifacts on external tomcats).

Comment: I doubt it would work, there have been internal changes in tomcat which aren't reflected in the code for Spring Boot 1.4.

Comment: OK. But is there a way to change that version at all? I am ready to upgrade `spring-boot` version to `2.0.0.RELEASE` however that has tomcat version `8.5.28`

Comment: Just specify the version you want to use (assuming you are using the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as the parent of your project.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are using spring boot gradle plugin and spring boot starters ..you can customise the version by setting maven project properties in build.gradle.

`ext['tomcat.version'] = '9.0.45'`

for maven

```
<properties>
    <tomcat.version>9.0.45</tomcat.version>
<properties>
```

You can find all the external dependencies that can be customised in [spring-boot-dependencies](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml)

Comment: Too bad you couldn't give the whole example of how to do it. This a partial answer

Comment: Using gradle was able to by doing `def tomcatVersion = '9.0.30'` and    
`dependencies {                                                                                     
    implementation "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:${tomcatVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:${tomcatVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:${tomcatVersion}"        
}`

Comment: If were using maven, add dependencies within `<dependencyManagement>`, otherwise project might not change it at all.

Comment: I wouldn't give Tomcat 10 as an example, as it is jakartified and the current Spring libraries won't work with it.

Comment: Does this still work in Maven with newer versions of Spring boot? It seems like there no longer exists a `pom.xml` to overwrite: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies

Answer (score 19):

Late to the party I know, was looking for a similar issue, thought I'd share a more literal hint.

You need to override the properties **set in spring's parent pom**  (which is mandatory for this) to suit your case (and compatibility too):

```
<properties>
......
    <tomcat.version>9.0.5</tomcat.version>
......
<properties>
```

This is according to [Introduction to Spring][1]. Their example shows many other dependencies cherry-picked.
[1]: http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-starter-parent

Answer (score 4):

#### For maven projects

```xml
<properties>
  ...
  <tomcat.version>8.0.53</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
         <!-- NON-INFORMATIVE -->
         <!--   <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${bom.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>   -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

After changing the version by adding ext version in build gradle and trying to run application getting an error
Getting Error: .... nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMapping(Ljava/lang/String)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).